Can my cat forgive me after series of physical abuse?
Please I need help. I got a cat because I felt alone and thought she would make me feel better but it turns out I'm a horrible person. I carry out my aggression on my pussycat.
I feel very bad for hurting my cat and I don't want to do it again. She's my everything currently. But the issue is that she is now scared of me and is always hiding. Our relationship is on a downward slope. I feel very bad. How do I fix this?

https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28567/i-need-help-rebuilding-my-cats-trust-after-abusing-them-multiple-times

https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/37824/i-used-to-abuse-my-cat-is-it-best-that-i-get-rid-of-him-or-is-it-okay-if-he-st?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C22.4341

Frankly, it sounds like you should find a new home for the cat, for both her sake and yours, unless and until you can learn to either suppress your frustrations or take them out on inanimate objects, preferably somewhere that the noise won't scare the cat. If she's really "everything to you", please consider putting her needs ahead of yours.

Seconding the strong recommendation you rehome your cat to keep her safe, and then seek professional help for your own issues, which you are not going to be able to resolve on your own (especially with a convenient target you've used previously nearby). If your cat is "everything to you," please rehome her before you take her life.
